# Why does the following code use an e-mail address as a hostname?

Tags: java, sockets

At the moment, I am learning about sockets and as an example I am creating a finger client. I noticed the hostname is supposed to be an e-mail address and not a domain name in the following code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Finger {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String user;
        String host;
        if ((args.length == 1) && (args[0].indexOf("@") > -1)) {
            StringTokenizer split = new StringTokenizer(args[0],
                "@");
            user = split.nextToken();
            host = split.nextToken();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Usage: java Finger user@host");
            return;
        }
        try (Socket digit = new Socket(host, 79);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(digit.getInputStream()));
            ) {

            digit.setSoTimeout(20000);
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(
                digit.getOutputStream());
            out.print(user + "\015\012");

            boolean eof = false;
            while (!eof) {
                String line = in.readLine();
                if (line != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                } else {
                    eof = true;
                }
            }
            digit.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Error:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Shouldn't it be a domain name as email addresses are used to resolve the IP of email servers not finger servers?

Comment: This is not an email address, but a unix user@hostname mask, eg: admin@192.168.1.2 or root@localhost

Comment: When the socket is created, wouldn't the socket resolve the hostname first through dns. If this is the case, how would a dns server distinguish a finger address and an email address. For example: icculus@icculus.org is both an e-mail and a finger address?

Comment: Your code is splitting them up, so it sees root@192.168.0.1, then splits that into username root: host: 192.168.0.1, then tries to establish a socket to the host, one way to think of it is similar to an email address, but not quite, you're trying to use the finger protocol to check for user username at host 192.168.0.1, it's just a connection string, basically, even though it does bear resemblance to an email, and in fact could be a valid email address, if there's an sshd running on gmail.com and i say finger someuser@gmail.com it can be both a valid unix hostmask and a valid email address

Comment: Sorry, I realised my mistake.